# Could my question be voted to be undeleted?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed

Question - [How to convert a map transformation in scala to java without manually rebuilding the map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47251872/how-to-convert-a-map-transformation-in-scala-to-java-without-manually-rebuilding)

This question as I stated in my earlier meta post - [As a question-banned user on Stack Overflow should I delete my bad questions or edit them to ask some other question in their place?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362314/as-a-question-banned-user-on-stack-overflow-should-i-delete-my-bad-questions-or) was really bad and should have never been asked in the first place. But I studied into the functions more and edited the question after it was put on hold to be meaningful. Could it be looked at and voted to be undeleted if it is appropriate in its current version?

Comment: It's open now...